# Missing binaries in nservicebus 3.0 Azure sample projects

Tags: nservicebus, servicebus

I downloaded the nservicebus 3 sample projects and noticed that there were missing dependencies (for example nservicebus.hosting.azure.dll and others).

Do I really need to download and build the trunk to get these dlls? I also noticed that they are not available via nuget either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was resolved with the NSB 3.0.3 release.